# Can we add a new column or columns automatically to a database table

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a table where there are 3 columns "TaxGroup","Name" and "Value".But now i want to add a new column or more columns automatically.In brief,if a requirement came like to add "Cess" column after 1 year the code should be like it should create a column on its own or another column like "Sales Tax" after 2 years it should create a column on its own.So my question is there any way to write the code so that it can create a new column on its own.If there is no way to create then what are the reasons for it

Comment: You initially define a table and all it's columns with the DML statement [CREATE TABLE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_table.asp).  You can add and remove columns using [ALTER TABLE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp), provided the change doesn't violate any integrity constraints.  Most programming libraries that interface with your database support DML "create table" and "alter table".  Given that - what exactly is your question?

Comment: what is the programming language you are using?

Comment: RDBMS' generally don't work well with "automatically added columns", because there is 1) no 'native support' for such as the query must fit the existing definitions, and 2) some thought in design is required to maintain acceptable normalization.. that said, there are some products like SharePoint that rely extensively on updating table definitions (but these are done as the SP Objects are modified, not "dynamically during write"). Underneath this is done with the DML paulsm4 mention.

Comment: @Sahan Jsp and Java

Comment: @paulsm4 My question is to add a column automatically,while we are using create table we need to give a name,datatype,NotNull or Null,AutoInc all these.Can mysql does all these on its own without user writing the code??

Comment: @paulsm4   I got another doubt.Can we use the row ("Cess") of a table to be used to create as a column in another table

Comment: @user2864740 I got another doubt.Can we use the row ("Cess") of a table to be used to create as a column in another table

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell us what exactly do you mean by Automatic? I suppose you cannot just magically add a column to the table.

If you mean that you want a query to add a column to the table in future, then you can use the alter table query:

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name>
ADD <Column_Name(Cess)> <datatype(Number)>
```

Source: [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp)

If you mean to say that you want some programmatic way to add a column by just giving the column name as input and it should add the column name, then you can write a data persistence program in java or any other language you know and use the same query above in it and send the column name as input in that program.

I am not writing the entire code here as I am not clear what exactly you are looking for.

Please provide more clear picture of your expectation so we could help you better.